# How to use Dirac function to represent constraint in an integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, constraints

Hello and I want to do integral under constraint like:
$ \int_{f(x1,x2...xn) = 0}g(x1,x2,...xn)\rm dx1dx2...dxn $
some book told me I can use Dirac function to represent constraint as:
$ \int_{x1,x2...xn}g(x1,x2,...xn)\delta(f(x1,x2...xn))\rm dx1dx2...dxn $ 
but when I try it in practice I find something make me confused, here is an example:
I want to calculate circumference of an unit circle so I use integral as :
$ \int_{x}\int_{y}\delta(x^2 + y^2 - 1)\rm dxdy $
and we know $ \delta(f(x)) = \sum_{i=0}^N\frac{\delta(x-xi)}{\vert{\frac{\partial{f(x)}}{\partial x}} \quad\vert x=xi} $ xi is root of f(x)
so I take y as variable and $ y = \pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$
$\delta(x^2 + y^2 - 1)=\frac{\delta(y-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{2*\sqrt{1-x^2}} + \frac{\delta(y+\sqrt{1-x^2})}{2*\sqrt{1-x^2}}$
so $ \int_{x}\int_{y}\delta(x^2 + y^2 - 1)\rm dxdy = \int_{x=-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \rm dx = \pi$
the constant 2 is missing, and if I change the constraint to $ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 1 $ which is equivalent to $ x^2 + y^2 = 1$ , then
$\delta(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - 1)=\frac{\delta(y-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} + \frac{\delta(y+\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ it's two times than before, in fact different type of constraint which have same effect can result to different scalar so it make me confused
how to integrate constraint to integral to avoid the scalar error?

Comment: How is $\delta(s)$ defined for a real number $s$?

Comment: δ(s) is Dirac delta function, tends to inf when s-->0, equal to 0 otherwise.you can serach in google with key word 'Dirac delta function' to see other property.

Comment: dimensionally, the equation is a bit off ... the dimension of the delta function is the reciprocal of its argument ... since the argument is length squared, it's dimension is one over length squared ... multiply by the two differential (each with dimension length) and the integral you've posed has zero dimension ... whereas what you're looking for ( a circumference) should have dimension of length to first power

Comment: in order to correct dimensionality, change to $\delta \left( \sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One needs to insert a gradient
   $${\rm Vol}(\{x \in\mathbb{R}^n|f(x)=0\})~=~ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \!\mathrm{d}^nx~ \color{red}{|\nabla f(x)|} \delta(f(x)) \tag{1}$$
   for purely geometric reasons to ensure that the volume doesn't depend on the parametrization of the constraint function $f$.
2. *Example: The circumference of the unit-circle $\mathbb{S}^1=\{x \in\mathbb{R}^2|f(x)=0\}$.* Here the constraint function is $f(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2-1$. Then $\color{red}{|\nabla f(x)|=2}$ for $x\in \mathbb{S}^1$.
   Hence
   $${\rm Vol}(\mathbb{S}^1)~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~ \int_0^{2\pi} \!\mathrm{d}\phi\int_0^{\infty} \!r\mathrm{d}r~ \color{red}{2} \delta(r^2-1)~=~2\pi. \tag{2}$$
3. See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54778/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: Thanks for your guide, I study the link you attach and what does the $δ{^n}(f(x))$ mean here? Take my example in the question, f(x,y) = $x^2 +y^2-1$, so is $δ{^n}(f(x,y))$  a 2x1 vector?How to define it? and for  |∇f(x)|, I think  |∇f(x)| =[2*x 2*y] , a 1x2 vector is it correct?

Comment: Ups. That was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you, I miss the volume before so I got the wrong result. :)

Comment: +1 for the moderator of PSE.